# Incorrect tagging of verb in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I used the a tagger with the treebank corpus to POS tag a sentence using NLTK. The sentence is "The cat ate the dog". For some reason, it tags "ate" as NN while it should be a verb. Any clues?

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag  
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
pos_tag(word_tokenize("The cat ate the dog"))
```

**[out]:**
    `[('The', 'DT'), ('cat', 'NN'), ('ate', 'NN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('dog', 'NN')]`

Comment: Clues as to what? POS tagging isn't perfect. Try a different model if this sentence is important to you.

Comment: which pos tagger are you referring to? what is the code?

Comment: @alvas The default one. Just posted the code, I believe it uses the Penn Treebank tagset.

Comment: @larsmans I was afraid that's what it means. Is there a way around? A custom tagger perhaps, assuming I have tagged sentences available? This sentence isn't important but I am afraid I will run into more.

Comment: There's probably a model learner somewhere in NLTK, but be aware that it's an educational tool. Also, don't fear, *measure*. Machine learning POS tagging is a statistical process, and you can't draw conclusions based on a single sentence.

Comment: take a look at 5.4 onward here to try other taggers: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html

Comment: @larsmans If NLTK is an education tool - do you know of other packages, whether free or paid, that could be usable in a commercial quality product?

Comment: Yes, it seems like you've found the weakness of the default `pos_tag` POS tagger in `NLTK`.
If you take a look at the code, you see that the default tagger is built using `maximum entropy (MaxEnt)` and `PennTreeBank` tagged corpus: `https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/tag/__init__.py`. I can only suggest that you retrain the model and then try retagging ;P

Comment: Try HunPos API in NLTK, it's a more reliable tagger =) http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/hunpos.html

Comment: @alvas Will give it a whirl tonight. Thanks

Comment: I think the default tagger provides upto 96% of accuracy. Have a look at this link which might help you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nltk-users/Wvl_8znhO1o