# Not detecting adjectives through the NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

Here is the code

```
text = "I bought a men's rose & gold quartz watch."
tk = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tg = nltk.pos_tag(tk)
print tg
```

The result is

```
[(u'I', 'PRP'), (u'bought', 'VBD'), (u'a', 'DT'), (u'men', 'NNS'), (u"'s", 'POS'
), (u'rose', 'NN'), (u'&', 'CC'), (u'gold', 'NN'), (u'quartz', 'NN'), (u'watch',
'NN'), (u'.', '.')]
```

In this case I need rose and gold to be detected as adjectives. Could someone show me how?

Comment: How to improve nltk's pos tagger is a typical question. Maybe you find useful these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017237/working-with-the-python-nltk-how-can-i-improve-the-accuracy-of-the-pos-tagger and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822194/how-to-override-the-pos-tags-assigned-to-a-text-by-nltks-pos-tag

Comment: The domain is the description on products for sale. I was hoping that NLTK would detect the structure of the sentence and infer adjectives from that. The product range is unlimited so it might not be possible to train NLTK for it.

Comment: POS tagger generally do better with `NN` or `VB`.

Comment: it's the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452328/incorrect-tagging-of-verb-in-nltk